# Debian console has first character hidden (outside of monitor)

Tags: debian, resolution, console

The issue we are hitting with our server is quite odd. The terminal's first line(s) is printed outside the monitor and we tried changing resolution without success. Reducing buffer width (`stty columns 78`) didn't do it either.

Setup :

- Debian jessie
- VGA KVM switch

[image: Picture of monitor]

As you can see on the picture above (`ifconfig`), the first letter is missing `oot` instead of `root`, `th0` instead of `eth0` and `o` instead of `lo`

The monitor and KVM switch work fine with other servers in the rack

Thanks

Comment: Is that a CRT monitor or is it just distortion in the photo making it appear curved? If the latter, then there may be an "Auto" button or menu option on the monitor which will make the picture fit on the display.

Comment: 'Auto' did the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As posted in the comments by Andre Morton, the solution was simply to press the `'Auto'` button on the LCD monitor